# Replace KeyboardEvent to work with Aid for Android

Tags: actionscript-3, air, keyboard-events

I have made ann app that works fine on windows. The problem is that i use the following event listener:
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
but when i compile my app for Android (Air 23) this event is not working.
So i would like to ask which event i will use for AIR in Android to replace that event?

Comment: You only get finger tap / mouse click listeners working on Android as replacement for key down. Work with that. Also do you think its important for us to know context of the `key_down` listener or even what happens inside function `keyDownHandler`? Only mention, if it helps, to give a more specific answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank yoy very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your event listener to the Native Application instance:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler)
```